# Creating a custom post type and subpages with same slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a custom post type with the 'has_archive' to 'false' to be able to create a page with the same slug as the custom post type: 'Test'.

I want to create subpages / child pages for the 'Test' page but i receive error 404 page.

There is a way to prioritize pages over custom post type?

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_test' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_test() {
  $labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Test', 'test' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Test', 'test' ),
    );

  $args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Test', 'test' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'test'),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
      );
  register_post_type( "test", $args );
}
```

Comment: Flush you permalinks at "Settings > Permalinks"

Comment: i tried it already and the nothing changed

Comment: @ascadrianinn you want your urls to follow www.example.com/test/sample?

Comment: @OrlandoP. Yes. The "Test" page to have a child page (../test/sample)
Also to be able to use the post type "test".

Answer (score 1):

```php
function custom_rada_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Porady',
        'singular_name'       => 'Porady',
        'menu_name'           => 'Porady',
        'parent_item_colon'   => 'Kategoria rodzica',
        'all_items'           => 'Wszystkie porady',
        'view_item'           => 'Wyświetl poradę',
        'add_new_item'        => 'Dodaj poradę',
        'add_new'             => 'Dodaj poradę',
        'edit_item'           => 'Edytuj poradę',
        'update_item'         => 'Zaktualizuj poradę',
        'search_items'        => 'Wyszukaj poradę',
        'not_found'           => 'Nie znaleziono',
        'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Nie znaleziono w koszyku',
    );
        
    $args = array(
        'label'               => 'rada',
        'description'         => 'Szablony porad',
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( '' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => 'porady',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'porady', 'with_front' => false ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-help',
    );

    register_post_type( 'rada', $args );
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rada_type', 0 );
```

1. Create custom post type
2. Create Page with slug - **porady**
3. Add rewrite rule

   ```php
   add_action('init', function () {
       add_rewrite_rule('porady/?$','index.php?pagename=porady', 'top');
       flush_rewrite_rules();
   }, 1000);
   ```
4. After change Flush you permalinks at "Settings > Permalinks"
   And you will receive - site.com/porady(page with slug porady) and site.com/porady/article(custom post article)

Comment: Nothing changed.
I tried this and the problem was not solved.

From your example i want to be able to create:

1) site.com/porady/article -> Custom Post Type;

2) site.com/porady/ -> Page (works already because 'has_archive' is set to 'false';

3)site.com/porady/test -> Page (i receive the Error 404);

Comment: My main problem is with creating a child page for 'Porady'(in your example)
I can create a 'Porady' page without making a rewrite_rule by disabling the 'has_archive' property to post type.

Answer (score 1):

[Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) has answered this question and worked fine!

just add this function to function.php

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/396970/60877

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_parse_request' );
function my_parse_request( $wp ) {
    $post_type = 'rada'; // set the post type slug
    // and the "porady" below is the Page slug

    // This code checks if the path of the current request/page URL begins with
    // "porady/" as in https://example.com/porady/child-page-name and also
    // https://example.com/porady/child-page-name/page/2 (paginated request).
    // We also check if the post_type var is the post type set above.
    if ( preg_match( '#^porady/#', $wp->request ) &&
        isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'] ) &&
        $post_type === $wp->query_vars['post_type']
    ) {
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'name'      => $wp->query_vars['name'],
        ) );

        // If a (child) Page with the same name/slug exists, we load the Page,
        // regardless the post type post exists or not.
        if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
            $wp->query_vars['pagename'] = get_page_uri( $posts[0] );

            unset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'],
                $wp->query_vars[ $post_type ] );
        }
    }
}
```